# Error when browsing to public Careers profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I can not access my public CV link in [careers.stackoverflow.com](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/). My profile link was: [careers.stackoverflow.com/salmanwahed](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/salmanwahed). I have accessed the careers site after some time and saw this error.

> [image]

Is it an error or the website has been changed which I don't know?

Comment: FYI, that is not 404 error, but customized 500 error. (404 is Page Not Found, which looks different and got totally different meaning.)

Comment: @Patrick huh, didn't notice. Well, all good now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the bug report! Surprise surprise, it was a null reference exception. Programming is hard!

I've fixed the issue and all CVs should now be visible once more.

Comment: It's working now! Great :)